# Squid vs mod_proxy (apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, squid, mod-proxy

New to servers, been hovering on http://highscalability.com/ for some days. Most of the architectures there show that people are using squid for proxy. Apache also provided mod_proxy which to a noob eye seems pretty much the same. Is there a perticular reason to opt for squid instead of mod_proxy?

Thanks

Comment: Not so much an answer, but see http://varnish-cache.org/ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's the same, but with *a lot* better suited architecture.

since you don't run applications on Squid, all code is reviewed with the same goal: serve from cache, or get out of the way.

also, it's event-driven, and single-threaded; giving the best performance / resource utilization ratios.

of course, there's also Varnish and Nginx.... both claim to be even better (i'm *really* impressed by Nginx)